# Fixing Colors on Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes

**Update** Okay, so changing the Gnome Tweak Tool 'Global Dark Theme' to false, did the trick, but I liked the dark theme for my other applications. Any chance I can control these colors on a per application basis?

I just installed firefox developer edition on Ubuntu 14.04 (gnome shell) and I'm having color problems. No matter how I change the firefox themes I still have scroll bar and input field colors that cause problems...

[image]

The white boxes are just covering up personal data.

Any help would rock!